# Storing Data in Mysql or Cache vs Calculating in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis

I have a table with 8000 Vendors (Think a Seller on Amazon).

Each Vendor has around 100 items in their purchase history with columns such as price, tax, date.

Each Vendor has columns such as State, Region, Type.

I am creating a Html Table to display Vendors Purchases History by month. However, I also want to compare it to Average by State, Region, and Overall.

My question is, how should I store these aggregate averages. Should I create tables for each one, store them in cache (Redis), calculate in mysql, or calculate in php?

I am using Laravel on the backend. The main problem i have with storing them in their own table is a don't want a bunch of tables like purchase_histroy_state with columns date, state_id, and total. Currently, the server times out when I try to calculate with php.

Comment: No code, no help. What have you done so far?

Comment: I have fully functional enterprise application. I have the (html) tables for each Vendor with total purchase history calculated by month already however I am trying to add comparisons to aggregate average data. However, I am getting server timeouts using the same methods (PHP Loop) to calculate total purchase history for each month. Sorry for the lack of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8,000 vendors x 100 items is 800,000 items that you're asking PHP to trawl through, calculate and store in memory every time it is ran.

If you're wanting a quick and dirty solution - then consider setting up a SQLite database with a denormalized structure, and appropriate indexes. Databases are designed to do this sort of stuff - even SQLite.

I wouldn't recommend this as a long term solution though as it's not really scalable - but it might help in the early development stages to figure out what you need.